# Does Bravery gives you bonuses against Demoralize Opponent?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, fighter

Does [Bravery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter#TOC-Bravery-Ex-) from the Fighter gives him any bonuses against a [Demoralize Opponent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/intimidate) made against himself?

In the description it says "The DC of this check is equal to 10 + the target’s Hit Dice + the target’s Wisdom modifier." I doesn't state anything about any additional bonuses from Bravery or another class feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already stated by @rojomoke, Bravery does not assist you in this case, as it specifically grants a bonus to Will Saves against Fear. However, as a fighter, there is an option available through [Advanced Weapon Training,](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter#Advanced-Weapon-Training) from Weapon Master's Handbook. Specifically helpful in your case is the Advanced Weapon Training: Armed Bravery:

> Armed Bravery (Ex) The fighter applies his bonus from bravery to Will saving throws. **In addition, the DC of Intimidate checks to demoralize him increases by an amount equal to twice his bonus from bravery.** The fighter must have the bravery class feature in order to select this option.

((Emphasis mine))

So, to recap, *Regular Bravery does not increase the DC of Demoralize checks against you.* However, *A Fighter with Armed Bravery gets double their Bravery Bonus to the DC of Demoralize checks against them.*

Comment: Possibly relevant to this question is this FAQ: http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9svt (it clearly states demoralize is a fear effect).

Answer (score 6):

Bravery gives you a bonus specifically to Will saving throws. It doesn't increase your Wisdom, or your Wisdom modifier.  The Demoralize Opponent class feature doesn't give the target a saving throw, so Bravery doesn't help.

Comment: Agreed, Bravery is Will Save vs. Fear and Intimidate: Demoralize Opponent is not a save, but a check your opponent makes against you.

As mentioned in below link, you might ask GM to house rule it, but then you get into the issue if Paladin's are immune to Intimidates b/c of immunity to fear.

[related link](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ko66?Intimidate-Question).